# How can I import field names from a list or dictionary using prettytable in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, prettytable

Every examples I saw the user knows the number and the names of columns. What if my field names are in a list or in a dictionary and I don't know the number of them?

I read that the right code would be:

```
t = PrettyTable()
t.set_field_names("first","second","third")
```

but in my case names are inside a dictionary named columns:

```
columns = {column0: "first", column1: "second", column3: "third"}
```

I remind the number of columns is unknown for me. I tried with:

```
for x in range(0,len(columns)):
    target="column"+str(x)
    t.set_field_names(columns[target])
```

or with a list:

```
columns = ["first","second","third"]
t = PrettyTable()
t.set_field_names(columns)
```

but everytime error is the same:

```
 File "time_based_blind.py", line 105, in <module>
    t.set_field_names(columns)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prettytable.py", line 217, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: set_field_names
```

Comment: try unpacking: `t.set_field_names(*columns)`

Comment: don't know why but it's not working. same error.

Answer (score 0):

PrettyTable has no attribute `set_field_names`
you might change that to 

`columns = ["first","second","third"]
t = PrettyTable(columns)`